# Python Kivy how do I press multiple keys at once?

Tags: kivy

I am making a simple game in the coding language python in the module Kivy, where a guy moves across and around the screen using "wasd" commands. The problem I have ran into is not being able to press multiple keys at the same time. For example, if the player wants to press "w" and "d" at the same time to go diagonal in the upper right, they can't. It only lets them go one direction at a time. Below is some of my code.

```py
    class MainScreen(RelativeLayout):
        def __init__(self, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(**kwargs)
            self.guy_size = dp(50)
            self.velocity = 3
            self.acceleration = 0.5
    
            with self.canvas:
                Color(1, 0, 0)
                self.guy = Ellipse(pos=(100, 400), size=(self.guy_size, self.guy_size))
    
            self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(self.keyboard_closed, self)
            self._keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self.on_keyboard_down)
            self._keyboard.bind(on_key_up=self.on_keyboard_up)
    
            Clock.schedule_interval(partial(self.move_guy, 'nothing'), 1/60)
    
        def keyboard_closed(self):
            self._keyboard.unbind(on_key_down=self.on_keyboard_down)
            self._keyboard.unbind(on_key_up=self.on_keyboard_down)
            self._keyboard = None
    
        def on_keyboard_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
            global RUNNING
            if keycode[1] == 'w':
                self.move_guy('w')
    
            if keycode[1] == 's':
                self.move_guy('s')
    
            if keycode[1] == 'a':
                self.move_guy('a')
    
            if keycode[1] == 'd':
                self.move_guy('d')
    
            if keycode[1] == 'w' and keycode[1] == 'd':
                self.move_guy('wd')
    
    
            return True
    
        def on_keyboard_up(self, keyboard, keycode):
            pass
    
        def move_guy(self, direction, *largs):
            x, y = self.guy.pos
            if direction == 'w':
                y += 5
            if direction == 's':
                y -= 5
            if direction == 'a':
                x -= 5
            if direction == 'd':
                x += 5
    
            self.guy.pos = (x, y)
```

Comment: You will need to keep track of the status of your important keys. So, your `on_keyboard_down()` can keep some type of record that reflects that an important key was pressed. And your `on_keyboard_up()` can modify that record to reflect that an important key is no longer pressed. Once you have a record of what keys are currently pressed, another method can use that information to do the actual movement. That new method can be called from `on_keyboard_down()` and possible from `on_keyboard_up()`.

Comment: @JohnAnderson Thanks! That's what I ended up doing, and it worked. Thanks again!